# When removing old carpet in preparation for the installers should I also remove the old tack strip?

Tags: carpet

I've got carpet installers booked in to replace the carpet in 2 rooms of my apartment. In preparation for them I started removing the old carpet and then old carpet tack strips so they'd have a clear concrete floor to work on.

I got partway through removing the tack strips in the first room when I realised that the strips were probably in decent enough condition to be useable again (nails where a little rusty though).

Should I be removing the tack strips at all?

Comment: Ask the installers. On wood floors I would lean toward removing them, but on concrete they may want them left in place.  (Last time we had carpet replaced the neighbors must have thought we'd gone around the bend.  After pulling up the old carpet we spent evenings bouncing around trying to find all of the squeaky subfloor spots and screwing them down.  Also took the opportunity to cut holes in the floors to fix lighting fixtures in the ceiling below.  No concrete was injured.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tack strips are in good condition, most installers would prefer that they  remain. It saves them time and material and they will probably thank you for it.